# Trouble installing basic packages

Tags: networking, drivers, package-management, system-installation, gcc

I'm having difficulty installing the dependent packages required to install a r8125 driver.

I have one machine with Ubuntu 20.10 installed fresh. The network card requires the r8125 driver to function.  Installation of that requires gcc.  Manual installation of gcc has proved difficult, as the motherboard does not have WiFi built in and I have been unable to get USB tethering from an Android device to work.

Aside from manually downloading and installing every single package and dependency individually, all the solutions I've seen from other asked questions seems to assume that I have a working Linux machine connected to the internet with which to download all the required files.  I do not have such a machine, and am unable to obtain one.  I do have a Windows machine.

What I would like to know, is if there is either a version of Ubuntu that comes pre-installed with the build-essential metapackage, or a repository that exists where I can download all the required files to install that would enable be to install gcc.

Apologies if I have left any relevant information out, it is 8:30 AM and I've been trying to get this installed for the past 14 hours.

Comment: USB tethering is quite easy. You need to turn "USB modem" on in Android settings. It is unclear what is the problem.

Comment: Another option is to install a mainline 5.9+ kernel. Then you won't need drivers at all.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have enabled this option. The result is ifconfig -a shows the connection with ID "eth0." However, attempting to manually turn the connection on fails, as it gives me an error of something along the lines of "cannot resolve host." I tried adding a interfaces file in /etc/networks/ to configure it, but it did not work.  ifup command shows as not installed.

I will attempt the kernel upgrade.

Comment: @Pilot6 This has worked.  Updated kernel to 5.10 version, internet now works. Thank you so much.